# How to Model Object upload in API with form-data in asp.net Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

**Model Class**:

```
public class TestAspDotNetModelClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] file { get; set; }
}
```

**API Controller Action**:

```
public class ValuesController: ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostComplex(TestAspDotNetModelClass update)
    {
        if (update.fileProfile != null)
        {               
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        } 
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

File and value post in postman
[object post in API but API message show this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3OGC.png)

Comment: please see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53406028/5576498

Answer (score 0):

You Can handle the situation with two scenario.

> 1. You can use *HttpContext.Current.Request*

- Not required as you mentioned in model class byte[] property.

> > Ref. Link 1 : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/uploading-a-file-in-Asp-Net-web-api/

```
public class ValuesController: ApiController
{
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostComplex(TestAspDotNetModelClass update)
    {
        if (update.fileProfile != null)
        {
           HttpResponseMessage result = null;  
           var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;  
           if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)  
            {  
                var docfiles = new List<string>();  
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)  
                {  
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];  
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);  
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);  
                    docfiles.Add(filePath);  
                }  
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);  
            }  
            
        } 
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
 }
```

> 2. You can go with same as you mentioned byte[] that is not possible to create json thats why you can convert byte[] to *Base64String* then it is possible.
>
> > Ref. Link 2 : [Saving a base64 string as an image into a folder on server using C# and Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394129/saving-a-base64-string-as-an-image-into-a-folder-on-server-using-c-sharp-and-web)

Model Class

```
public class TestAspDotNetModelClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Base64Stringfile { get; set; }
}
```

API Controller Action

```
public class ValuesController: ApiController
{
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostComplex(TestAspDotNetModelClass update)
    {
        if (update.Base64Stringfile != null)
        {
            // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
            byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(update.Base64Stringfile);
            // Convert your byte[] to file
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        } 
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay. if I do not mention the file/byte[] property, then if I try to receive multiple files and model objects, then I can't catch flies. and you know if I used base64String if any way string is missing, then corrupted a file. and also you know my code style don net Core Possible(please if possible in asp.net, help me)